# trying to figure out a weird math formula

Tags: python, math

So I am making an attack timeout based on a speed rating for a program that I am writing, but I am no genius when it comes to math. As it is i have a formula like so `speed = lambda x: x/50` The base speed rating defaults at 100, so the attack would occur every two seconds at `speed(100)`. Now what I want is for the attack to occur faster at a higher speed rating, and slower at a slower speed rating. I.e. `speed(98)` would return something higher than 2, while `speed(101)` would return something lower than 2. These numbers are just examples but the main point is that is there a formula that can return a lower number based on a higher base number, and vice versa?

Example: `speed(101); returns x < y` and `speed(98); returns x > y` y being a constant number such as 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
def speed(score, attacks_per_second):
    """
    computes actual attack speed for a player with `score`, 
    assuming a player with a score of 100 could attack at
    `attacks_per_second`.  Lower scores are better.
    """
    return attacks_per_second * (100 / score)
```

```
>>> speed (100, 2)
2.0
>>> speed (120, 2)
1.6666666666666667
>>> speed (80, 2)
2.5
```

---

edit:  Since I misread the first time, and you want higher scores to give lower speeds, invert the 100/score into score/100.  The original is preserved here:

```
def speed_inverse(score, attacks_per_second):
    """
    as above, but higher scores are better
    """
    return attacks_per_second * (score / 100)
```

```
>>> speed (120, 2)
2.4
>>> speed (80, 2)
1.6
```

Comment: If I'm reading right you have the desired relationship inverted.

Comment: @dsm: I think you're right, Now I've got both, with the first what I think he's asking.

Comment: @riyoken: wait, what?  You said "speed(98) would return something higher than 2".  The original would have speed(98) returning something *lower* than 2, and the new one has it returning something greater than 2.  How was it right the first time?

Comment: wait it seems as if there was a typo on his first function, but the output is right.

Comment: def speed(x, y): return y* (100/x) is what i think he meant for the first function, and this is what works.

Answer (score 1):

That's just division.  :)

```
attack_delay = 200 / speed
```

Now with `speed = 100`, you'll have two seconds between attacks.  With `speed = 50`, you'll have four seconds between attacks.  `speed = 200` gives you one attack per second.